# How to add Text or Logo watermark to PHP photo upload script function?

Tags: php, image, upload, watermark

Thank you for reading my question. I am struggling with an image upload function of a script which I bought through CC. I am terrible with PHP hence only doing trial and errors to add watermark on bottom-right of the uploaded image. The script itself works as far as the image uploading goes. I only get errors when I try to include the lines for adding watermark... I am pasting the upload script itself without my bad watermark code lines...

```
$width = IMAGE_MIN_WIDTH;
$height = IMAGE_MIN_HEIGHT;
$size_max = IMAGE_MAX_SIZE;


if (!@getimagesize($_FILES['Image1']['tmp_name']) == false) {
    if (!$add) {
        if ($obj->image != 'none') {
            $uploaded_image = 'none';
            unlink(IMAGE_UPLOAD_FOLDER . $obj->image);
        }
    }

    $array = getimagesize($_FILES['Image1']['tmp_name']);
    if (($_FILES['Image1']['size'] <= $size_max) && ($array['0'] >= $width) && ($array['1'] >= $height)) {

        $image = addslashes($_FILES['Image1']['tmp_name']);
        $uploaded_image = md5(basename($_FILES['Image1']['name'])) . md5(time()) . '.' . pathinfo($_FILES['Image1']['name'],
                PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $uploadfile = IMAGE_UPLOAD_FOLDER . $uploaded_image;
        $size = getimagesize($image);
        $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image));

        $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($size[0], $size[1]);
        imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size[0], $size[1], $size[0], $size[1]);

        imagedestroy($src);
        imagepng($dst, $uploadfile);
        imagedestroy($dst);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

```
$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image)); 
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('img/logo-small.png'); 
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); 
$marge_right = 10; 
$marge_bottom = 10; 
$sx = imagesx($stamp); 
$sy = imagesy($stamp); 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
imagepng($im, 'uploads/'.$new_file_name);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($size[0], $size[1]); 
imagecopyresampled($dst, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size[0], $size[1], $size[0], $size[1]);
```

Comment: There is an [example in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php)

Comment: There are actually 2 [examples in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php)

Comment: And another [example here](https://www.phpjabbers.com/put-watermark-on-images-using-php-php20.html)

Comment: Also it would make a better question if you show us your attempt, then it looks more like a _can you help fix it_ than a _can you do it for me_ question

Comment: Sorry guys @RiggsFolly I signed up here recently, I didn't realise question could not be edited . I dont want to create a new question .. so I'm pasting my attempt here . Thanks
....

Comment: ...
$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image));
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('img/logo-small.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
     $marge_right = 10;
     $marge_bottom = 10;
     $sx = imagesx($stamp);
     $sy = imagesy($stamp);
     imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
     imagepng($im, 'uploads/'.$new_file_name);

        $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($size[0], $size[1]);
        imagecopyresampled($dst, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size[0], $size[1], $size[0], $size[1]);

Comment: Edit done for you. Not sure why you cannot edit your own question

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly, these are the additional lines I was hoping would add my watermark... but I get a blank page, no error, no image upload, no watermark. If I remove those lines, image uploads fine without watermark. I wonder what I did wrong :( 

And please, how to edit question? I cannot find any edit option on my side. Thx

Answer (score 0):

you have to give Public/Absolute Path for **Font arial.ttf**.

Solution is tested in Laravel 5.8.

```
function watermarkImage ($SourceFile, $WaterMarkText, $DestinationFile,$imgUrl) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($SourceFile);
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($SourceFile);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
   $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0);
   $font = public_path('fonts/arial.ttf');
   $font_size = 8;
   imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 10, 20, $black,$font , $WaterMarkText);
   if ($DestinationFile <> '') {
    imagejpeg ($image_p, $DestinationFile, 100);
   } else {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
  };
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($image_p);
return  $imgUrl;
}
```

Comment: For those wondering what `public_path` is, it's Laravel specific and builds a absolute path to the font file. You will probably need to edit that to be your own path.